# Lucene: Payloads and Similarity Function --- Always same Payload value

Tags: java, lucene

**Overview**

I want to implement a Lucene Indexer/Searcher that uses the new Payload feature that allows to add meta information to text. In my specific case, I add weights (that can be understood as % probabilities, between 0 and 100) to conceptual tags in order to use them to overwrite the standard Lucene TF-IDF weighting. I am puzzled by the behaviour of this and I believe there is something wrong with the Similarity class, that I overwrote, but I cannot figure it out.

**Example**

When I run a search query (e.g. "concept:red") I discover that each payload is always the first number that was passed through MyPayloadSimilarity (in the code example, this is 1.0) and not 1.0, 50.0 and 100.0. As a result, all documents get the same payload and the same score. However, the data should feature picture #1, with a payload of 100.0, followed by picture #2, followed by picture #3 and very diverse scores. I can't get my heard around.

Here are the results of the run:

```
Query: concept:red
===>  docid: 0 payload: 1.0
===>  docid: 1 payload: 1.0
===>  docid: 2 payload: 1.0
Number of results:3
-> docid: 3.jpg score: 0.2518424
-> docid: 2.jpg score: 0.2518424
-> docid: 1.jpg score: 0.2518424
```

What is wrong? Did i misunderstand something about Payloads?

**Code**

Enclosed I share my code as a self-contained example to make it as easy as possible for you to run it, should you consider this option.

```
public class PayloadShowcase {

 public static void main(String s[]) {
     PayloadShowcase p = new PayloadShowcase();
     p.run();
 }

public void run () {
    // Step 1: indexing
    MyPayloadIndexer indexer = new MyPayloadIndexer();
    indexer.index();
    // Step 2: searching
    MyPayloadSearcher searcher = new MyPayloadSearcher();
    searcher.search("red");
}

public class MyPayloadAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    private PayloadEncoder encoder;
    MyPayloadAnalyzer(PayloadEncoder encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(source);
        filter = new DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter(filter, '|', encoder);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }
}

public class MyPayloadIndexer {

    public MyPayloadIndexer() {}

    public void index() {
        try {
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("D:/data/indices/sandbox"));
            Analyzer analyzer = new MyPayloadAnalyzer(new FloatEncoder());
            IndexWriterConfig iwconfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_1, analyzer);
            iwconfig.setSimilarity(new MyPayloadSimilarity());
            iwconfig.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);

            // load mappings and classifiers
            HashMap<String, String> mappings = this.loadDataMappings();
            HashMap<String, HashMap> cMaps = this.loadData();

            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwconfig);
            indexDocuments(writer, mappings, cMaps);
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while indexing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void indexDocuments(IndexWriter writer, HashMap<String, String> fileMappings, HashMap<String, HashMap> concepts) throws IOException {

        Set fileSet = fileMappings.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iterator = fileSet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            // unique file information
            String fileID = iterator.next();
            String filePath = fileMappings.get(fileID);
            // create a new, empty document
            Document doc = new Document();
            // path of the indexed file
            Field pathField = new StringField("path", filePath, Field.Store.YES);
            doc.add(pathField);
            // lookup all concept probabilities for this fileID
            Iterator<String> conceptIterator = concepts.keySet().iterator();
            while (conceptIterator.hasNext()){
                String conceptName = conceptIterator.next();
                HashMap conceptMap = concepts.get(conceptName);
                doc.add(new TextField("concept", ("" + conceptName + "|").trim() + (conceptMap.get(fileID) + "").trim(), Field.Store.YES));
            }
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> loadDataMappings(){
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<>();
        h.put("1", "1.jpg");
        h.put("2", "2.jpg");
        h.put("3", "3.jpg");
        return h;
    }

    public HashMap<String, HashMap> loadData(){
        HashMap<String, HashMap> h = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> green = new HashMap<>();
        green.put("1", "50.0");
        green.put("2", "1.0");
        green.put("3", "100.0");
        HashMap<String, String> red = new HashMap<>();
        red.put("1", "100.0");
        red.put("2", "50.0");
        red.put("3", "1.0");
        HashMap<String, String> blue = new HashMap<>();
        blue.put("1", "1.0");
        blue.put("2", "50.0");
        blue.put("3", "100.0");
        h.put("green", green);
        h.put("red", red);
        h.put("blue", blue);
        return h;
    }
}

class MyPayloadSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float scorePayload(int docID, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {
        float pload = 1.0f;
        if (payload != null) {
            pload = PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes);
        }
        System.out.println("===>  docid: " + docID + " payload: " + pload);
        return pload;
    }
}

public class MyPayloadSearcher {

    public MyPayloadSearcher() {}

    public void search(String queryString) {
        try {
            IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("D:/data/indices/sandbox")));
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            searcher.setSimilarity(new PayloadSimilarity());
            PayloadTermQuery query = new PayloadTermQuery(new Term("concept", queryString),
                    new AveragePayloadFunction());
            System.out.println("Query: " + query.toString());
            TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 999);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
            System.out.println("Number of results:" + hits.length);

            // output
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
                System.out.println("-> docid: " + doc.get("path") + " score: " + hits[i].score);
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while searching: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `MyPayloadSimilarity`, `PayloadHelper.decodeFloat` call is incorrect. In this case, it's also necessary to pass the `payload.offset` param, like this:

> `pload = PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, payload.offset);`

I hope it helps.

Comment: No, still the same result. :(

Comment: @ralfb , at your example code, `MyPayloadSearcher.search` is setting `PayloadSimilarity` (which doesn't exist here, but may exist in your code) instead of `MyPayloadSimilarity`. It may be the reason why you are not seen the change. Please, make sure which `PayloadSimilarity` class you are using.

Comment: Oh my god! That was it! I know it was something dumb on my side. Thank you very much for kicking my brain a bit. In the future, I will also create separate projects and make sure the sandbox code is isolated and not inside the same project that invites copy-paste error. Thanks a lot Juliano! :)